# Check if a string is included in an array and append if not (C)

Tags: arrays, c, loops, unique, c-strings

I have 2 arrays, one called 'edges' which contains a list of city names and another called cityNames which is initialised as an empty string.

What I would like to do is move through the edges array element by element and see if it is included in the cityNames array. If it is, move onto the next element in edges, if it isn't, append the value to the cityNames array.

The code below adds the edges[i].startCity to the cityNames array but it does not check for duplicates and I can't figure out why.

```
for (int i = 1; i < noEdges; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < noCities; j++) {
            if(strcmp(edges[i].startCity, cityNames[j].cityName) != 0) {
                strcpy(cityNames[i].cityName, edges[i].startCity);
            }
        }
        noCities += 1;
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think what you need is strstr and strcat

Comment: I would consider sorting the array edges and add the next item, if it is not equal to the previous one. This should save a lot of calculation time (reduction form O(n*n) to O(n log(n))

Comment: This code does not check for duplicates, and does not append anything anywhere. Start with an append. Write a **function** that does an append. Make sure it does NOT accept an index of an edge or any other irrelevant data. It should accept a string, an array, and its effective size, modify the array, and return the new size, which is the effective size incremented by one, and this should be the only function that is allowed to change the effective size. The effective size at the beginning is zero.

Comment: (con'd) Next write a **function** that checks for duplicates. It should accept a string, an array, and its effective size, and return 1 if if the string appears in ANY position in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that:

- `edges` is an array of structures of a known length `noEdges`, each structure containing a *string* (either a char pointer or a char array)
- cityNames is an array of structures for which the size is at least the number of distinct name (it could be `noEdges` or the size of the `edges` array)
- the `cityNames` structure contain a char array element for which the size is at least the longest name + 1 (+1 for the terminating null)

Then the following code could give the unique names:

```
noCity = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < noEdges; i++) {
        int dup = 0;       // expect edges[i].startCity not to be a duplicate
        for (int j = 0; j < noCities; j++) {
            if(strcmp(edges[i].startCity, cityNames[j].cityName) == 0) {
                dup = 1;   // got a duplicate
                break;     // no need to go further ...
            }
        }
        if (dup == 0) {    // not a duplicate: add it to cityNames
            strcpy(cityNames[noCities].cityName, edges[i].startCity);
            noCities += 1; // we now have one more city
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A good idea to start with would be to ditch working with strings if you can (or at least manipulate strings when actually needed).

You could start off by assigning each city name a number, that way you have an array of ints which is quicker and easier to work with.
Scanning for duplicates becomes trivial as you would now only be comparing numbers.

When you need to display the actual text on screen or write the city names to file, you could use the indexes associated with the city names to retrieve the appropriate textual representation of the index. You could then replace the data type of your cityNames[] to ints. This makes each 'node' which the 'edges' connect a number instead of text.

```
char* actualCityNames[n]; //array holding all city names with duplicates, could be a file also
char* indexedCityNames[n];//array with indexed cities (in order of appearance in actualCityNames, i.e. not alphabetical order)
//indexedCityNames will most likely not use up N slots if duplicates occur
//this is why there is a second counter for the size of indexed cities

int indexedCount = 0;//number of unique city names
int duplicates = 0;

//loop for actualCityNames slots
for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
    
    //loop for indexedCityNames
    for(int j=0; j<indexedCount; j++){
        
        //strcmp returns 0 if both strings are the same
        if(strcmp(actualCityNames[i],indexedCityNames[j]) == 0){
            //duplicate found, mark flag
            duplicates = 1;
        }
    } 
    
    if(!duplicates){
        strcpy(indexedCityNames[indexedCount],actualCityNames[I]);
        indexedCount++;
    }
    duplicates = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code snippet does not check for duplicates because in the inner loop the if statement appends `startCity` as soon as a first `cityName` is encountered that is not equal to the current  `startCity`.

Moreover in this statement

```
strcpy(cityNames[i].cityName, edges[i].startCity);
                ^^^
```

there is used an incorrect index.

And the variable `noCities` shall be incremented only when a new `startCity` is appended.

Also the outer loop should start from the index equal to 0.

Rewrite the loops the following way

```
int noCities = 0;

for ( int i = 0; i < noEdges; i++ ) {
    int j = 0;

    while ( j < noCities && strcmp(edges[i].startCity, cityNames[j].cityName) != 0 ) {
        ++j;
    }
        
    if ( j == noCities ) strcpy(cityNames[noCities++].cityName, edges[i].startCity);
}
```